# Android Listview with different layout for each row?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create Listview in which I want different layout for all different row.
Then how can I create custom adapter for set different layout for different row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row

Comment: use a custom listview with a custom adapter

Comment: can you provide medemo code for this

Comment: @ArvindKanjariya http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868194/android-xml-layout-for-a-listview-with-different-items. but you need to know how to use custom listview and adapter

Comment: you can make in the getView method of the custom adapter and add the dynamic layout what you want by making a switch case in it...

Comment: @ArvindKanjariya Refer the link http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/08/android-listview-with-multiple-row.html. May it will help you.

Answer (score 9):

You need to extend your `Adapter`, and override its `getView` method.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int resource;

    // Here you set ‘resource’ with the correct layout, for the row
    // given by the parameter ‘position.’
    //
    // E.g.:
    //
    // switch (someArray[position].type) {
    //   case SOME_TYPE_A: resource = R.layout.a; break;
    //   case SOME_TYPE_B: resource = R.layout.b; break;
    //   ...
    // }

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);

    // Here you initialize the contents of the newly created view.
    //
    // E.g.:
    // switch (resource) {
    //   case R.layout.a:
    //      TextView aA = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.aa);
    //      aA.setText("View 1");
    //      ...
    //      break;
    //   case R.layout.b:
    //      TextView bB = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.bb);
    //      bB.setText("View 2");
    //      ...
    //      break;
    //   ...
    // }

    return rowView;
}
```

For more examples on adapters and how to extend them, see the links below.

- http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown
- http://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/

Answer (score 7):

create regular adapter , in the create_view function inflate the row xml layout according to the row type.

for example

```
@Override   
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
         .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

     if (position % 2 == 0 )
        xml_type = R.layout.row_one
     else
         xml_type = R.layout.row_two

     View rowView = inflater.inflate(xml_type, parent, false);
}
```