# Android - Custom listview changes while scrolling?

Tags: android, listview, scroll

My listview keeps changing while scrolling. I'm trying to display the messages in "messages" variable. Everything is fine when i scroll first time. But when i scroll again, the textviews overlap each other. I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
public class DisplayMessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message> {

    Context context;
    int resource;
    ArrayList<Message> messages = null;

    public DisplayMessageAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Message> messages) {
        super(context, resource, messages);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.messages = messages; //list of messages to display
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        final MessagesHolder holder;


        if(row == null)
        {
            //Log.i("row-null","row-null");
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);

            holder = new MessagesHolder();
            holder.sent  = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.sent_message);
            holder.received = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.received_message);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }

        else
        {
            //Log.i("holder-not-null","holder-not-null");
            holder = (MessagesHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Message message = messages.get(position);


        if(message.sent != null)
        {
            holder.sent.setText(message.sent);
            holder.received.setBackground(null);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.received.setText(message.received);
            holder.sent.setBackground(null);
        }

        return row;
    }

    static class MessagesHolder
    {
        TextView sent;
        TextView received;

    }

}
```

Layout xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
      <TextView android:id="@+id/sent_message"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/sent"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"

        android:textSize="15sp"
         />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/received_message"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/rcvd"
          android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
          android:textColor="#000000"
          android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
          android:textSize="15sp"
           />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You have this  `holder.received.setText(message.received);` and this  `holder.sent.setText(message.sent);` twice remove one of them

Comment: @GrIsHu no need for that coz op extends ArrayAdapter and has  `super(context, resource, messages);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your conditions as below to set the values in your `TextView`.
In your below code the all if conditions are same. That does not make any difference.

```
  if(message.sent != null && message.received != null)
    {
        Log.i("adapter","both");
        holder.sent.setText(message.sent);
        holder.received.setText(message.received);
    }
    else if(message.sent != null)
    {
        holder.sent.setText(message.sent);
        //holder.received.setBackground(null);
    }
    else if(message.received != null)
    {
        holder.received.setText(message.received);
        //holder.sent.setBackground(null);
    }
```

Change it as below:

```
  if(message.sent != null && message.received != null)
    {
        holder.sent.setText(message.sent);
        holder.received.setText(message.received);
    }
    else
    {
        holder.sent.setText("NA");
         holder.received.setText("NA");
    }
```

Comment: Actually, this is a dead code(was seeing if this was executing).  I have changed it to the one i was originally using. A message will have either sent or received with data. Not both.

Comment: @user3128485 i think what you need is different row types. one of receive one for message. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868194/android-xml-layout-for-a-listview-with-different-items

Comment: You mean a row for send and a row for received?

Answer (score 0):

Temproary Solution :

The problem seems to be in the holder and it's use. It works now if i dont use the holder class for performance boost. Although i'm not sure how to use the holder properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  I had a progress bar in my rows.  My problem is that I wasn't resetting the progress bar every time get view was called.  You must reset ever asset.