# Android SeekBar in ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, seekbar

I have multiple SeekBars in a LinearLayout that is in a ScrollView. I don't want my seekbar to take the touch event when I am scrolling up and down. Any ideas?

EDIT:

I tried using ListView, problem is I need a horizontal layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a multi layout listview by extending the BaseAdapter, in xml layout create a list item having Seekbar.

and dont forget to override getViewItemType and getViewTypeCount.
same type of question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868194/android-xml-layout-for-a-listview-with-different-items)