# Adding variable number of tags to ListView

Tags: android, xml, json, listview, tags

Brand new to Android programming and just dinking around.

I've built a ListView that is populating posts.  I've successfully loaded a JSON and can populate my custom layout with title, post content, and timestamp.

The problem is I can't figure out how to add tags (akin to the screenshot below of Zite's app, eg "Bosnia", "Visualization", "Security").  I have up to three tags that I want to add (location, school, friend) so I put three buttons in the layout.  I can change the button text with the incoming JSON of course, but not every item has all three tags (for instance one item has only location, while another has location & school).  So I want buttons to only appear when I have text for them, and I'll use gravity to force them left.

My first thought was a nested listview.  The internet told me that is bad.  Despite my searching, I found no tutorials or advice.  **But this feels like a known problem, any suggestions for learning resources?**

Below is my relevant XML and java.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/feed_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="@string/fTitle"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/feed_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/feed_title"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:text="@string/fContent"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/feed_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/feed_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:text="@string/fTime"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/feed_like"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/feed_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/feed_time"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/feed_flag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/feed_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/feed_like"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/feed_like" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_below="@+id/feed_time"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/feed_tag_Locale"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="@string/fTagLocal"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/feed_tag_Network"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fTagNetwork"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/feed_tag_Friend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fTagFriend"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

```
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(view == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_feed, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.feed_title);
        holder.postTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.feed_content);
        holder.timeTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.feed_time);
        holder.localeButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.feed_tag_Locale);
        holder.networkButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.feed_tag_Network);
        holder.friendButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.feed_tag_Friend);

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) getItem(i);
    JSONObject subObject;
    JSONObject traitsObject;

    String postTitle = "";
    String postContent = "";
    String postTimestamp = "";
    String postLocale = "";
    String postNetwork = "";
    String postFriend = "";

    if (jsonObject.has("postID")) {
        //postTitle = jsonObject.optString("title");
        postTimestamp = jsonObject.optString("timePosted");
        try  {
            subObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Content");
            postTitle = subObject.optString("title");
            postContent = subObject.optString("content");

            traitsObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Poster");
            postLocale = traitsObject.optString("location");
            postNetwork = traitsObject.optString("network");
            postFriend = traitsObject.optString("friends");


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    //if (jsonObject.has(""))

    holder.titleTextView.setText(postTitle);
    holder.postTextView.setText("I see you " + postContent);
    holder.timeTextView.setText(postTimestamp);
    holder.localeButton.setText(postLocale);
    holder.networkButton.setText(postNetwork);
    holder.friendButton.setText(postFriend);

    return view;

}
```

[image]

Comment: no have different layouts and based on the data type you inflate appropriate layouts

Comment: Check this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868194/android-xml-layout-for-a-listview-with-different-items

Answer (score 0):

At the end of getView, change this:

```
holder.localeButton.setText(postLocale);
holder.networkButton.setText(postNetwork);
holder.friendButton.setText(postFriend);
```

to this:

```
if(!postLocale.matches("")){
    holder.localeButton.setText(postLocale);
}
else{
    holder.localeButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

if(!postNetwork.matches("")){
    holder.networkButton.setText(postNetwork);
}
else{
    holder.networkButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

if(!postFriend.matches("")){
    holder.friendButton.setText(postFriend);
}
else{
    holder.friendButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```