# Items cannot be added to the listview after scrolling the listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Well After inserting the text and image by using  the Onclick Listener Functionality when the Screen becomes full i.e when The list becomes Scrollable  and when I try to add the new item and when I scroll down the list,I see the first Item of the List has been added to the list instead of current item which has to be added to the list.

CustomListView

```
public class CustomListView extends ListActivity {
ArrayList<Item> imageArry = new ArrayList<Item>();
//CustomImageAdapter adapter;
private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;

Button a, b;
EditText abc;
String result;
ListView dataList;

Item abcd;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    abc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.one);
    a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


    mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this);


    a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            result = abc.getText().toString();


            mAdapter.addItem(new Item(result));


        }
    });


    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            mAdapter.addSeparatorItem(new Item(R.drawable.google));


        }
    });
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);


}
```

}

MyCustomAdapter

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_SEPARATOR + 1;
Context context;


private ArrayList<Item> mData = new ArrayList<Item>();
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

private TreeSet<Integer> mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();

public MyCustomAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.context = context;
}

public void addItem(final Item item) {
    mData.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addSeparatorItem(final Item item) {
    mData.add(item);
    // save separator position
    mSeparatorsSet.add(mData.size() - 1);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return mSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public Item getItem(int position) {
    return mData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    Item myImage = mData.get(position);
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        switch (type) {
            case TYPE_ITEM:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.textlayout, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.resulttext);
                holder.textView.setText(myImage.getName());
                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.resultimage, null);
                holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.resultimage);
                holder.img.setImageResource(myImage.getImage());
                break;
        }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    return convertView;
}


public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
    public ImageView img;
}
```

}

Item.java

```
public class Item {

int image;
String name;

public Item(int image, String name) {
    super();
    this.image = image;
    this.name = name;
}
public Item(String name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
}

public Item() {

}

public Item(int image) {
    super();
    this.image=image;
}

public int getImage() {
    return image;
}
public void setImage(int image) {
    this.image = image;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.55"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"></ListView>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="230dp"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="a"
        android:id="@+id/button"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="b"
        android:id="@+id/button2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

textlayout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/resulttext"/>
```

resultimage.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/resultimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: You have `fill_parent`  for listview. that is gonna cover the whole screen

Comment: but i already used the fill parent for list view right

Comment: so its gonna take the full screen right. where is space for other elements. Also use `match_parent`

Comment: i used both wrap content and match parent but it is not working

Comment: you need to have image and text view in a single listview right. Use getViewItemType in adapter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868194/android-xml-layout-for-a-listview-with-different-items. See if this fits your requirement

Comment: i already tried this example but the problem is that text views and image views are added into one layout but when screen is filled it takes the again same items(previous ones in sequence).new items are added randomly

Comment: this is working perfectly until screen is not filled

Comment: What is your requirement? You want text and image in one row?. Search for custom listview you will find many examples

Comment: no my requirement is when i click send button i want text view to be add

Comment: when i click load button image view to be add to list view dynamically

Comment: just update the underlying data and call notifydatasetChanged to refresh listview

Comment: this approach is correct or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81699/discussion-between-pavan-kumar-parasa-and-raghunandan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is in getView method of Adapter, In listview, the view that is going off the screen will be reused instead of creating a new view, so the view will have the details for the first view.

Try replacing your getView method with the below one, it should solve your problem of first item appearing again.

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    Item myImage = mData.get(position);
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        switch (type) {
            case TYPE_ITEM:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.textlayout, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.resulttext);
                //holder.textView.setText(myImage.getName());
                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.resultimage, null);
                holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.resultimage);
               // holder.img.setImageResource(myImage.getImage());
                break;
        }

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
switch (type) {
case TYPE_ITEM:
                holder.textView.setText(myImage.getName());
                break;
 case TYPE_SEPARATOR:           
                holder.img.setImageResource(myImage.getImage());
                break;
}
convertView.setTag(holder);
    return convertView;
}
```

So, we need to set the details again the view which is recycled.

Comment: My solution helped or you had some other issues also?